# Как снять нагрузку с БД?

Tags: php, mysql

К примеру, на сайте 10 000 страниц и сайт популярный, то есть каждую секунду кто-то, что-то открывает. Разумеется обновления страниц подсчитываются как минимум `UPDATE tab1 SET ...` но ведь это страшная нагрузка на `БД`.

Я подумал сделать так, при каждом открытии страницы, будет записываться в файл со строкой к примеру `id=5,views=+1` ну или как-то так, чтобы потом этот файл лишь спарсить и занести все значения в БД одним разом.

Возможно я немного непонятно объяснил, но думаю Вы поймете)

Comment: Лучше не дергать базу данных на каждый просмотр, а складировать просмотры в какое-нибудь NoSQL-решение, откуда оптом обновлять счетчики в базе данных раз в 5/10/60 минут (в зависимости от нагрузки).

Comment: Запись в файл может оказаться медленнее записи в БД. Вы убедились, что  у вас узкое место - именно работа с БД?

Comment: Если уж кешировать информацию о показах, то в какой нибудь memcached, что бы диски вообще не грузить

Comment: Redis (in-memory-persistant), Memcached используйте и будет вам счастье. Раз в N-минут дергайте оттуда данные и отправляйте в БД, вот и всё.

Comment: @Mike можно пример?

Comment: google -> "memcached"

Comment: @Mike уже нашел))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вам нужно определиться, что вы хотите сделать в принципе и зачем.

1) если вы хотите отслеживать активность пользователей на страницах сайта

- есть счетчики
- есть яндекс-метрика
- есть логи веб-сервера

БД здесь можно не использовать, но:

2) если вы хотите отслеживать активность пользователей с помощью БД, ничего страшного при записи 100-1000 запросов/секунду в таблицу с логами/апдейтами посещаемости у вас не случится - если только у вас не совсем уж хилый хостинг.

3) подключать технологии кэширования и т.д. следует только после того, как вы провели бенчмарки и поняли, что - даже если вы максимально оптимизировали запись в БД -  у вас все равно будут тормоза.

4) многое будет зависеть не столько от базы данных, сколько от движка сайта. Тяжеловесные и тормозные движки потребуют больше ресурсов, и могут тормозить/падать по памяти, хотя сама база прекрасно справилась бы. Посмотрите в [бенчмарк](http://blog.a-way-out.net/blog/2015/03/27/php-framework-benchmark/)

5) В файл писать не следует, у вас есть логи веб-сервера (он следит за корректностью лог-файла сам),  запись из многих потоков/запросов в один файл, скорее всего приведет этот файл в кошмарное состояние.

Comment: VPS: CPU - 2.4GHz, RAM - 1GB, OpenVZ

Comment: ну вот ты можешь взять, запустить скрипт в цикле и посмотреть, сможешь ли ты вставить в бд 100-500 запросов в секунду в локальную бд (с паузами в 0.5 секунд, чтобы скомпенсировать нагрузку скрипта и локального десктопа) , я более чем уверен, что сможешь, рам на инсерты не очень влияет, (хотя буферы можно увеличить в mysql). короче, прежде чем что-то конструировать - нужно измерить

Comment: иначе у тебя получится переусложненный стек технологий, который не оправдан нагрузкой

Comment: всё понял, но на счет паузы в 0,5 секунды, это как и где и зачем?

Comment: ну если ты в цикле вставляешь данные в бд, то делай sleep(0.5) поскольку ты на локальном компе тестируешь. если тестируешь со своего клиента на удаленном сервере - попробуй без пауз. короче прикинь ситуации с реальной и максимальной нагрузкой.

Comment: понял, а отследить что та с бд и сервером, что то вроде этого? http://ruhighload.com/index.php/2010/03/05/sysbench-testiruem-proizvoditelnost-mysql/

Comment: на счет движка, сайт самописный

Comment: вроде того, да. Но я обновил ответ, посмотрите в ссылку. Я более чем уверен, что у вас скорее движок/код станет узким местом, а не бд. 10к уников в день это даже для сайта на текстовых файлах допустимо :-) (в сутках 86.400 секунд). Если сайт самописный - то научитесь оптимизировать запросы и таблицы, а уже потом переживайте за производительность бд. Тот же фалькон, например, будет работать быстрее, чем ваш самописный код, скорее всего (это расширение для php  на языке C)

Comment: кстати на счет VPS, лучше ли будет перейти на сервер с такими же параметрами только KVM?

Comment: это а) отдельный вопрос б) я не знаю в) всегда нужно измерять :-)

Comment: а как на счет вопрос myisam или inno?) интернет-магазин - это я о таблице с товарами, `SELECT` часто разумеется, `UPDATE`, возможно `count(*)`

Comment: бери innodb, и почитай про транзакции. вопрос myisam/innodb  уже лет 10 как неактуален. и да, классика. скачай-купи-своруй-одолжи книгу "оптимизация mysql"